# Sending a crash report automatically with that name of the Form and Function in which the crash has happend?

Tags: c#, vb.net, crash-reports

I am looking into implementing a crash report on my application in Vb.net or C#, that will send the crash log to me (crash like division by zero) . I tried (1st. Try and Catch, 2nd. Crashreport.Net) which both sends automatically the crash log. but the problem with the first one is if I have many functions and forms, it makes it complex to add Try and Catch in every single function. if I use the Crashreport.net , it sends a report  including Only the name of the Form in which the crash has happend. 
I am want to implement a crash-report method to include both the name of the Form and the name of the Function in which the crash has happend.

P.s. There are some paid softwares out there that can solve my problem, but i am trying to do it freely. 
P.s. I am a junior programmer. please forgive me if I couldn't make it more clear.

Comment: Take a look at Fody https://github.com/Fody/Fody This can be setuped to "weave" your crash report code, into the assembly after it is buid so that you don't need to add try/catch to every function. This can be automatically added by Fody. Good Luck

Comment: @ Mihail Shishkov Thanks, aren't there any DLL package like Crashreport?

Comment: ask yourself a question. What would I do with the crashreport when I get it? "What if I know what's the exact function that "crashed", what do I do next? The answer is: this is not enough, I need context". You need context on the Command/Event that caused the crash. At least the input parameters of the Command/Event. For example - user enters data on a form and presses a button - the app crashes. In order to fix the problem you'll need that data included in the report.

Answer (score 0):

MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name <= It returns the name of the function. not sure if you looking for that tho

Comment: Yes , i need exactly the name of the function in which the crash happens.
Should I use it in Crashreport.net or else where ?
The CRASH log is emailed to me, I want also the name of the function 
 inside the log.

Comment: well the line of code i wrote might do the work it c#

Comment: i use it in try catch : ex : LogHelper.Write(ex.Message + " => " + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, LogHelper.LEVEL.Error);

Comment: I see, This is used in Try and Catch! which needs to be added in every function!! Thank you , but i do not use Try and Catch.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add try. . .catch everywhere, you can use the global exception handler - you can find this by going to the Project Properties page, and clicking ApplicationEvents. Once there you can build an exception handler, extracting the stack trace from the exception, and display it, email it, or whatever.